# How to add custom whatsapp template message in Kivicare plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

in Kivi care clinic and patient management plugin, we can use whatsapp messages using Twilio. But I want to add birthday greetings for the patients via whatsapp. Can anyone help me, how can I create a custom whatsapp message template there and use it!

When I asked the support, they are saying you can try a developer help. Please help me on this..